# IOS Webpage - Not Allowed by Access Control Allow Orgin

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ajax, cross-domain

Im doing a simple ajax request like:`

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'http://' + serverIP + '/saveJSON.php',
crossDomain: true,
data: 'helloooooooooo',
dataType: 'text',
success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var value = responseData.someKey;
     console.log(responseData);
    console.log(textStatus);
},
error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('POST failed.' + responseData);
    console.log(responseData);
    console.log(textStatus);
}
});`
```

And when running this in IOS Safari i get the error ...

"XML HttpRequest cannot load ...... Orgin ... is not allow by Access Control Allow Orgin

... Is to replace long URL's

I know I chrome I can by pass this by loading chrome with a -disable-web-security or other flags.

How can I get around this in iOS ? Security is not an issue as the devices will be locked down and only allow communication between certain IP address's.

Is there any other method of retrieving information from a server php script in JavaScript? That will be allowed?

Also any links to good websites for AJAX communication with PHP would be helpful.

Just to add, All my pages the client uses/sees are HTML (.html) and the server side is (.php)

Also when following [THIS](http://enable-cors.org/) link for sorting this issue i added the header to my IIS 6 for my htmls are hosted and the ipad still doenst allow this.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) header.

In PHP it can be doing for example by adding new header in your PHP file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: @user983969 This changes must be server-side

Comment: So i add it in to my php file im loading to get the data? or in the html file on the server? Or is it an actual server file?

Comment: I understand now, but all the files the client recive are .html its only the php file that the client posts to that is .php , sorry for confusion i edited my question

Comment: What web-server are you using? apache?

Comment: Currently using a portable USB server for the php files